# Assigning a char pointer to char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, strtok

I am starting to studying C and I already run into few problems. 
I want to parse a file and store the results of each line in a structure.
My structure looks like:

```
struct record {
    char x[100];
}
```

Then, whenever I use strtok to parse a line in some file.txt,

```
struct record R;
...
char *token;
token = strtok(line, "\t");
```

token returns a pointer to the string and whenever I print it, it is correct string. I want to assign token to x, such as `R.x = token`, but I get an error, "char x[100] is not assignable". Is it possible to convert this pointer token to actual char array or what would be the best way to store the results into the structure?

Comment: You cannot assign arrays like that. Use `memcpy()` to fill it with the data you want it to contain.

Answer (score 5):

The error says it all. **Arrays are not assignable**. You need to copy each character one by one and then append a NUL-terminator at the end.

Fortunately there is a function that does this for you. The name of the function is `strcpy` and it is found in the `string.h` header.

To fix your issue, use

```
strcpy(R.x,token);
```

instead of

```
R.x = token;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `strcpy` after making sure that the string fits in the array:

```
#define LEN(array) (sizeof (array) / sizeof (array)[0])

if (strlen(token) < LEN(R.x)) {
   strcpy(R.x, token);
} else {
   fprintf(stderr, "error: input string \"%s\" is longer than maximum %d\n", token, LEN(R.x) - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy` stops when it encounters a NULL, `memcpy` does not.
So if you array have `0x00` eg. `\0` in middle,you should use `memcpy` rather than `strcpy`.